# how to validate address using regex scala spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, bigdata

I want to validate address in my data, the validate format is 
123 Block-B avenue. i.e number space character with some special character than space than only character. But when I tried to use regression it is not working I am writing like this

```
val x = if

("""^[-0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~]+(\.[-0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~]+)*\s*\[a-zA-Z,.-:]*\s*\[a-z]*\.""".
r.
findFirstIn
(Address)
 == N
one)

 { 

             false
           }
           else {
                 true}
```

But the above one is not working

```
123 xyx avenue.--> false

abc 986 street.--> false

1/1 block-D street.--> false

123 9876block park--> false

result should be

123 xyx avenue.--> true

abc 986 street.--> false

1/1 block-D street.--> true

123 9876block park--> false
```

can someone help here using scala spark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Using this Regex:**

```
"""\d+\W?\d+ [a-zA-Z]+\W?[a-zA-Z]+ [a-zA-Z.]+""".r
```

***In Scala REPL*:** *the desired results* for the given *test input* can be obtained as shown below.

```
scala> val Address = "123 xyx avenue."
Address: String = 123 xyx avenue.

scala> val x =if( """\d+\W?\d+ [a-zA-Z]+\W?[a-zA-Z]+ [a-zA-Z.]+""".r.
     | findFirstIn(Address)==None){false} else { true }
x: Boolean = true

scala> val Address = "abc 986 street."
Address: String = abc 986 street.

scala> val x =if( """\d+\W?\d+ [a-zA-Z]+\W?[a-zA-Z]+ [a-zA-Z.]+""".r.
     | findFirstIn(Address)==None){false} else { true }
x: Boolean = false

scala> val Address = "1/1 block-D street."
Address: String = 1/1 block-D street.

scala> val x =if( """\d+\W?\d+ [a-zA-Z]+\W?[a-zA-Z]+ [a-zA-Z.]+""".r.
     | findFirstIn(Address)==None){false} else { true }
x: Boolean = true

scala> val Address = "123 9876block park"
Address: String = 123 9876block park

scala> val x =if( """\d+\W?\d+ [a-zA-Z]+\W?[a-zA-Z]+ [a-zA-Z.]+""".r.
     | findFirstIn(Address)==None){false} else { true }
x: Boolean = false

scala>
```

Comment: can you please tell me why we use \d+\W?\d+ "w"-> that stands for character in first place and whats the use of "?" in the regex. @https://stackoverflow.com/users/9953316/raghhuraamm

Comment: ? Stands for 0 or one time of previous character is \W which is a non word character (special character)

Comment: \d+ stands for one or more digits.

Comment: thanks for your help https://stackoverflow.com/users/9953316/raghhuraamm, it worked.

Comment: I have inserted single literal space between first and second, second and third parts in address. If you suspect that there may be one  or more spaces in the data instead you may use \s+ in place of single literal spaces in regex expression.

Comment: yeah thanks , got it @https://stackoverflow.com/users/9953316/raghhuraamm